# WPF - Постраничная передача и отображение данных в приложение с DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, silverlight

Имеется приложение, в котором для вывода данных используется `DataGrid`. Сейчас эти данные загружаются в `DataGrid` из коллекции типа `ObservableCollection`, причём к `DataGrid` добавил возможность постраничной навигации, для чего использовал [PagedCollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(v=vs.95).aspx) из Silverlight. Всё вроде как отлично работает. Теперь меня интересует, есть ли какие-то встроенные средства добавить возможность не просто постраничного отображения, но и также постраничной **передачи** данных в `DataGrid` (вернее даже не в `DataGrid`, а в `CollectionView`, ассоциированному с этим `DataGrid`'ом)? Это было бы полезно в случае клиент-серверного приложения, когда на стороне клиента будет лишь та порция данных, которая в данный момент и отображается.

Спрашиваю про встроенные средства, т.к. в Silverlight постраничный `DataGrid` включён в стандартную библиотеку. Учитывая, что Silverlight ориентирован на Веб, логично предположить, что оный `DataGrid` как-то приспособлен для постепенной загрузки данных. Или это не так? (С Silverlight не работал, так что его устройство не знаю.)

> Не уверен, что корректно сформулировал вопрос, так что если это так - поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: А интересует только стандартный DataGrid в WPF?

Comment: @Gromy, пока да.

Comment: @Gromy, не сомневаюсь, что в библиотеках от сторонних разработчиков, особенно таких  крупных, как Telerik, большое количество полезных фич, о которых стандартной .Net-библиотеке даже не снилось. Так что наверняка там уже реализовано нечто подобное на то, о чём я спросил. Но мне кажется это может быть и в стандартном наборе.

Comment: По идее, вам дожна подойти виртуализация. Её смысл как раз в том, чтобы держать в памяти только отображаемые в данный момент данные. Посмотрите [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Но если верить [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/208792/), то виртуализирующей коллекции, которую можно было бы использовать в качестве источника данных, нет, и её придётся писать самостоятельно. :-(

Comment: @VladD мне кажется виртуализация, которую вы имеете в виду, отвечает за то, чтоб визуальные объекты(`TextBox` к примеру), не висел в памяти, когда он уже прокручен скролом. А вопрос скорее не про отрисовку элементов, а именно про такой тип коллекции, которому можно задать некоторый источник в виде `IQueryable` и что эта коллекция сама подгружала нужные данные при скролинге. @Dark_Clark, поправте если я не прав.

Comment: @Gromy: Про это как раз мой следующий комментарий. Но виртуализирующая коллекция — это уже не специфика WPF, а общая вещь.

Comment: @Gromy, да, что-то типа того. Только у меня навигация по DataGrid осуществляется с помощью кнопок переключения страниц. Я предполагал, что может быть в модели представлений данных (CollectionView) предусмотрено что-то подобное.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ссылки (в частности, за ссылку на статью). Почитаю про виртуализацию.

Comment: @Dark_Clark Я просто последние пол года использую `DevExpress` и там есть вот такая вот штука [EntityInstantFeedbackDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfCoreServerModeEntityInstantFeedbackDataSourcetopic) которая как раз решает Вашу проблему. Если поискать, возможно можно найти как он реализован внутри, но я что-то с ходу не нашел =(

Comment: @Gromy, спасибо за ссылку. Думаю, внутри эта штука реализована не очень просто. Тем более работает с Entity, до изучения которого я ещё не добрался. :) Так что это останется на потом. VladD дал ссылку на отличную статью. В ней приведена не очень сложная для понимания и при этом наверняка хорошо работающая виртуализирующая коллекция. По-моему, это как раз то, что нужно.

Comment: @VladD, а вы не в курсе, как работает `DataGrid` в Silverlight? Неужели в стандартной реализации все данные загружаются целиком? Спрашиваю даже скорее из любопытства.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: К сожалению, не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь этим примером:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GridPagingExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly PagingCollectionView _cview;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this._cview = new PagingCollectionView(
                new List<object>
                {
                    new { Animal = "Lion", Eats = "Tiger" },
                    new { Animal = "Tiger", Eats =  "Bear" },
                    new { Animal = "Bear", Eats = "Oh my" },
                    new { Animal = "Wait", Eats = "Oh my isn't an animal" },
                    new { Animal = "Oh well", Eats = "Who is counting anyway" },
                    new { Animal = "Need better content", Eats = "For posting on stackoverflow" }
                },
                2
            );
            this.DataContext = this._cview;
        }

        private void OnNextClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._cview.MoveToNextPage();
        }

        private void OnPreviousClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._cview.MoveToPreviousPage();
        }
    }

    public class PagingCollectionView : CollectionView
    {
        private readonly IList _innerList;
        private readonly int _itemsPerPage;

        private int _currentPage = 1;

        public PagingCollectionView(IList innerList, int itemsPerPage)
            : base(innerList)
        {
            this._innerList = innerList;
            this._itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get 
            { 
                if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount) // page 1..n-1
                {
                    return this._itemsPerPage;
                }
                else // page n
                {
                    var itemsLeft = this._innerList.Count % this._itemsPerPage;
                    if (0 == itemsLeft)
                    {
                        return this._itemsPerPage; // exactly itemsPerPage left
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // return the remaining items
                        return itemsLeft;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get { return this._currentPage; }
            set
            {
                this._currentPage = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPage"));
            }
        }

        public int ItemsPerPage { get { return this._itemsPerPage; } }

        public int PageCount
        {
            get 
            { 
                return (this._innerList.Count + this._itemsPerPage - 1) 
                    / this._itemsPerPage; 
            }
        }

        private int EndIndex
        {
            get
            {
                var end = this._currentPage * this._itemsPerPage - 1;
                return (end > this._innerList.Count) ? this._innerList.Count : end;
            }
        }

        private int StartIndex
        {
            get { return (this._currentPage - 1) * this._itemsPerPage; }
        }

        public override object GetItemAt(int index)
        {
            var offset = index % (this._itemsPerPage); 
            return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
        }

        public void MoveToNextPage()
        {
            if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount)
            {
                this.CurrentPage += 1;
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }

        public void MoveToPreviousPage()
        {
            if (this._currentPage > 1)
            {
                this.CurrentPage -= 1;
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Хамл:

```
<Window x:Class="GridPagingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="2">
                <Label.Content>
                    <Binding Path="CurrentPage">
                        <Binding.StringFormat>Current Page: {0}</Binding.StringFormat>
                    </Binding>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
            <Button Content="Next" Click="OnNextClicked" Margin="2"/>
            <Button Content="Previous" Click="OnPreviousClicked" Margin="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Animal" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Animal}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Eats" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Eats}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Видел этот пример [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974872/4937047), когда искал способ реализовать постраничный вывод данных в `DataGrid`. Тут речь идёт просто об отображении. В вопросе же я написал, что постраничное отображение сделал и теперь меня интересует постраничная **загрузка** данных в коллекцию-источник. В комментариях к вопросу пользователь VladD привёл полезные ссылки на статью с реализацией виртуализирующей коллекции. Пока это лучший вариант. Но меня всё ещё интересует, не имеется ли (как готовое решение) подобный механизм в Silverlight.